# firefox crash when have xul overlay with 2 xmlns properties

Tags: xml, firefox, crash, firefox-addon, xul

firefox crashing when run this empty addon code, when removing one 'xmlns' property avoid the crash

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <overlay
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
 xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
 </overlay>
```

how can I fix it? or how can I use html tags without 'xmlns:html'?

Comment: What do you mean by "crash"? I have production code like that, and no "crashes", FWIW. Could you elaborate a bit on what *exactly* you're doing and what is happening then.

Comment: crash means close firefox and open the 'crash reporter'..

Comment: @ירדןוידר that doesn't look like the problem. Are you sure it doesn't do the same if you comment the xmlns:html... line?